# How to capture delimiter in different array or designated key with preg_split?

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

**Update: first question resolved, was an issue with HTML/browser.**

**Second question:**
Is there a way to output the delimiters into a separate array?  If I use PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE, it mixes the delimiters into the same array and makes it confusing as opposed to PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE which designates its own key for the offset.

Code:

```
$str = 'world=earth;world!=mars;world>venus';
$arr = preg_split('/([;|])/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

DELIM CAPTURE example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => world=earth
    [1] => ;
    [2] => world!=mars
    [3] => ;
    [4] => world>venus
)
```

OFFSET CAPTURE example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => world=earth
            [1] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => world!=mars
            [1] => 12
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => world>venus
            [1] => 34
        )

)
```

Comment: Use `htmlspecialchars` for output containing angle brackets in HTML context. Else view source.

Comment: Yeah you're right.  Well that was dumb, I was using an online PHP editor and it looks like even without the pre, the output is being blocked because of the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you can't do this, but in this particular case you can do it quite easily after the fact:

```
print_r(array_chunk($arr, 2));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => world=earth
            [1] => ;
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => world!=mars
            [1] => ;
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => world>venus
        )

)
```

See also: [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array_chunk)

Answer (score 2):

You can't!

A way is to use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_split` to obtain what you want:

```
$pattern = '~[^;|]+(?=([;|])?)~';

preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $arr, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

The idea is to put an optional capturing group in a lookahead that captures the delimiter.

If you want to ensure that the different results are contiguous, you must add this check to the pattern:

```
$pattern = '~\G[;|]?\K[^;|]+(?=([;|])?)~';
```

pattern details:

```
\G           # the end of the last match position ( \A at the begining )
[;|]?        # optional delimiter (the first item doesn't have a delimiter)
\K           # reset all that has been matched before from match result
[^;|]+       # all that is not the delimiter
(?=          # lookead: means "followed by"
    ([;|])?  # capturing group 1 (optional): to capture the delimiter 
)            # close the lookahead
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I get from my Chrome browser when I run the PHP code:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] =&gt; world=earth
    [1] =&gt; world!=mars
    [2] =&gt; world<sun [3]=""> world&gt;venus
)
</sun></pre>
```

So `preg_split` function runs fine. It's just a problem in the array dump in HTML.

Comment: Yes, thank you, was an issue with the view not the code.  I have edited that question out.

Comment: @Devon You're super fast ;)